# Can we think of $E(X|Y)$ as a random variable on the measurable space of $Y$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have been confused by the conditional expectation operator as defined based on **sigma algebras**. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2572101/why-this-weird-definition-of-conditional-expectation) an earlier question I've asked.

However, I am beginning to understand it better now. 
Specifically I have one question:

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$ be a probability space. Then a random variable $X$ is a function $X:\Omega\to E$ where $(E,F)$ is another measurable space. Now, by $\sigma(X)$ we mean the sigma subalgebra of $\Sigma$ generated by $X$: $\sigma(X)=\{s\in \Sigma:X(s)\in F\}$.

Then the conditional expectation of another random variable $Y:\Omega \to \mathbb R$, denoted by $E(Y|X)$ is the conditional expectation $E(Y|\sigma(X))$. But by the standard definition of conditional expectation w.r.t. a sigma algebra, ([see the definition here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2572101/why-this-weird-definition-of-conditional-expectation)) this is only uniquely defined (almost surely) up to a measure on $\sigma(X)$ (unless I'm mistaken). That is, it is not uniquely defined as a function on $\Omega$, not even "almost surely". That is, there are many different random variables defined on $\Omega$ that correspond to the desired behaviour of $E(Y|X)$, because we only require this random variable to be measurable on $F$, not on $\Sigma$.

**This motivates my following question: Instead of thinking of $E(Y|X)$ as a random variable on $(\Omega,\Sigma, P)$, should we instead think of it as a random variable on the sample space $(E,F,\mu_X)$ (where for any $f\in F:$ $\mu_X(f):=P(X^{-1}(f))$?**

(perhaps this is obvious to you, but my book states it otherwise).

---

**EDIT:** Let me clarify further why I find the definition that $E(Y|X)$ is a map from $\Omega\to \mathbb R$ confusing, and why I would think it has to be a map from $E \to \mathbb R$.

I understand that the definition of $E(Y|X)$ is a map from $\Omega\to\mathbb R$. However, I don't see why, and why it is not instead a map $E\to \mathbb R$. The reason I find this confusing is twofold: firstly, it seems to me that the condition that $E(1_A E(Y|G))=E(1_A Y)$ for all $A\in G$ is so broad, that for example $E(Y|X)=Y$ also satisfies it. In other words, why not simply pick $E(Y|X)=Y$, and not even write down the condition at all? (This still leaves the first condition, but are there any non-degenerate cases where $Y$ is not $\sigma(X)$-measurable?). In any case, the condition does not seem to pin down a random variable on $\Omega\to \mathbb R$ that corresponds to what we want, *unless* we require that $E(Y|X):E\to \mathbb R$, in which case it will be a function of $X$.

Secondly, if $E(Y|X)$ is a map $E\to \mathbb R$, then we know the value of $E(Y|X)$ *even if we have a degenerate distribution of $X$*. That is, $E(Y|X=x)$ will simply be the single value $E(Y|X)(x)$, but if $E(Y|X)$ is a mapping from $\Omega \to \mathbb R$, then how do we know what $E(Y|X=x)$ is? There may be many different $\omega \in \Omega$ consistent with $X(\omega)=x$, so what is $E(Y|X=x)$ then? The answer seems to be undefined, because there are many different mappings $E(Y|X)$ consistent with the conditions in the definition of $E(Y|X)$ (such as for example $E(Y|X):=Y$).

**I must be making a mistake somewhere. I think I might be wrong about assuming that $E(Y|X)(\omega):=Y(\omega)$ satisfies the condition, but I cannot see how it doesn't.**

---

**EDIT 2:** Another attempt at explaining my confusion.

Here is why I cannot see why the definition of $E(Y|X)$ gives us a unique variable: Take the following sample space: $\Omega=\{1,2,3\}$. With $\Sigma=\mathcal P(\Omega)$, and $P(1)=P(2)=P(3)=1/3$. Moreover, let the random variable $X$ be defined as follows: $X(1)=X(2)=0,X(3)=1$, and $Y$ be defined as follows: $Y:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ and $Y(\omega) =\omega$. Moreover, $\sigma(X)=\{\{1,2\},\{3\},\Omega, \emptyset\}$

Then according to the definition $E(Y|X):=E(Y|\sigma(X))$ must satisfy the condition that $E(1_A E(Y|X))=E(1_A Y)$ for all $A\in \sigma(X)$. 
However, there are many examples of functions $f:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ that satsify this condition, because the element $\{1,2\}\in \sigma(X)$ allows for many different possibilities. We only need that $0.5\cdot f(1)+0.5\cdot f(2)=0.5\cdot Y(1)+0.5\cdot Y(2)=1.5$ and $f(3)=3$.

For example:

- $f(\omega):=Y(\omega)$, or
- $f(1):=-999, f(2):=1002,f(3):=3$, or
- $f(1):=1.5,f(2):=1.5, f(3):=3$.

But it is only the last of the three examples that we actually are interested in, isn't it? The first one does not really capture conditional expectation, and the second one is just absurd. Moreover, these three functions are not "all equal almost surely",

Comment: The correct source and target spaces are $X:\Omega\to E$, $Y:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ and $E(Y\mid X):\Omega\to\mathbb R$. In particular, $E(Y\mid X)$ is definitely not defined on $E$ but $E(Y\mid X)=g(X)$ almost surely, where $g:E\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: It seems like you are suggesting that $E(Y\, |\, X)$ depends only on the law of $X$, and this is not true at all.

Comment: @Jason, Why not? Given $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$, for any random variable $Z:\Omega \to T$, we have that $E(Z)$ is a constant $t\in T$, correct? Why wouldn't we have $E(Z|X)$ be a $t_X\in T$ whose value depends on the realization of $X$?

Comment: Again, $E(Y\mid X)$ depends on the **joint distribution** of $(X,Y)$ in the sense that if $(X',Y')=^d(X,Y)$ and $E(X\mid Y)=g(Y)$ almost surely then $E(X'\mid Y')=g(Y')$ almost surely. But assuming only that $X=^dX'$ does not suffice.

Comment: @Did, I know it depends on the joint distribution, I was assuming this in the background by assuming that $E(Y|X)$ is generated for a specific $P$.

Comment: ?? The joint distribution is not $P$, but the image of $P$ by $(X,Y)$, that is, the measure $\mu$ on the target space of $(X,Y)$ defined by $\mu(B)=P(\{\omega\in\Omega:(X(\omega),Y(\omega))\in B\})$ for every suitable $B\subseteq E\times\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Did, Does this contradict what I said? a single $P$ still corresponds to a single joint distribution, doesn't it? (in so far as we only care about $X$ and $Y$, and therefore, consider different $P$ that generate the same joint distribution to be equivalent).

Comment: Sorry but your last formulation, together with the preceding ones you posted here, makes that I am unable to discern if you saw the light or not. Maybe you did? Your last comment to @Gono's answer seems to indicate you did not, though (confusing random variables and their distributions).

Comment: @Did, Ok. I definitely don't think I have "seen the light", no. But I do think I understand the difference between a random variable and their distribution. A random variable is simply a map from every point in the sample space, to some measurable space (usually $R$). for example, in the sample space of a coin flip $\{H,T\}$, we might have $X(H)=5$, or $X(H)=\Gamma(\cdot)$ (in this case the measurable space might be the space of continous functions on $R$). A probability distribution over $X$ induced by a probability distribution over the sample space, is a probability measure on the (cntd)

Comment: measurable space of $X$ (In my notation: $(E,F)$), giving the measure space $(E,F,\mu_X)$. Please tell me if this is wrong. Also, I can't see where my mistake in that comment to @Gono's answer is.

Comment: @Did, I've edited the question.

Comment: As already said by others, $E(Y\mid X)$ is **not** characterized by its distribution only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be having trouble with the definition of conditional expectation. Given a probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$, a sub-$\sigma$-field $\mathcal F\subset\Sigma$ and an integrable random variable $Y:\Omega\to\mathbb R$, we say $Z:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is a conditional expectation of $Y$ given $\mathcal F$ if $Z$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable and, for every $A\in\mathcal F$,
$$E(Z\mathbf1_A)=E(Y\mathbf1_A).$$
This definition, on its own, gives you neither existence nor uniqueness of conditional expectation. However, a theorem does: conditional expectation always exists, and is unique up to null sets in $\mathcal F$, and so we may safely write $E(Y|\mathcal F)$ for the conditional expectation. You seem to think that this does not fully define $E(Y|\mathcal F)$ since multiple random variables satisfy the given conditions, but these random variables are all equal almost surely, so they are effectively the same.

You ask why $Y$ itself is not a candidate for this. Well, if $Y$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable, then it is! But in many situations of interest, $Y$ is *not* $\mathcal F$-measurable. If $\mathcal F$ is of the form $\mathcal F=\sigma(X)$ for some random variable $X$, then as others have pointed out, $Y$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable if and only if $Y=g(X)$ for some function $g$. However, *by definition*, $E(Y|\mathcal F)$ is still defined as a random variable on $\Omega$.

What about if there is $\omega_1,\omega_2\in\Omega$ such that $X(\omega_1)=X(\omega_2)=x$? In that case, one must have $E(Y|\mathcal F)(\omega_1)=E(Y|\mathcal F)(\omega_2)=g(x)$ - this is an easy exercise using the definition. So there is no contradiction there. Indeed, it is this fact which allows us to demonstrate the existence of such a $g$ (and therefore make sense of the informal notation $E(Y|X=x)$, which if $P(X=x)=0$ could be undefined).

Finally, as to why we don't consider conditional expectation as a function on the probability space $(E,F,\mu_X)$ - this loses too much information. Switching from an abstract probability space to the law of a given random variable is a very useful tool when you have only one random variable, but as soon as you have a second you lose any information about the dependence. To give you an explicit example: suppose $E=\mathbb R$ with its Borel $\sigma$-field, let $X_1,X_2$ be independent $\mathcal N(0,1)$, and let $Y=X_1$. Then $E(Y|X_1)=Y$, but $E(Y|X_2)=0$. How would be able to distinguish these two cases if we only defined $E(Y|X)$ on $\mathbb R$ with the probability measure $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}dx$?

Comment: "but these random variables are all equal almost surely, so they are effectively the same." This is precisely the thing that I don't see. please see my EDIT 2 in my question.

Comment: Your second edit continues to ignore the other extremely important part of the definition of conditional expectation: $E(Y|\mathcal F)$ must be $\mathcal F$-measurable. So if $\mathcal F=\{\emptyset, \{1,2\}, \{3\}, \Omega\}$, then necessarily $E(Y|\mathcal F)$ must be constant on $\{1,2\}$ (check this for yourself if you do not immediately see why).

Comment: The fact that two random variables being equal almost surely means they may be treated as identical is fundamental to measure theoretic probability theory - if this concept is still unclear to you, I recommend you pick up your favorite introductory textbook on probability theory and go through definitions and examples until you are more comfortable with the idea.

Comment: I know very well what almost surely means. I just found out where my problem was: I was simply misinterpreting what it means for $E(Y|X)$ to be $G$ measurable... I was spending so much time on condition 2 because I thought that caused me confusion, that I forgot to spend time on condition 1... It's a bit embarrassing, and I think it makes the question rather useless for others, so maybe I should delete this question? Thanks in any case for your help, because I now understand my earlier confusion, and your answer helped. (Same for @Did).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have the right idea.  There's an interesting fact about $\sigma(X)$: if $Y : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable, then there is a measurable function $g : E \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $Y = g(X)$.

Let's apply this to $\mathbb{E}(Y \, \mid \, \sigma(X))$.  This is a $\sigma(X)$-measurable random variable so there is a function $g : E \to \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$\mathbb{E}(Y \, \mid \, \sigma(X))(\omega) = g(X(\omega)).$$  It is suggestive to  define $\mathbb{E}(Y \, \mid \, X = x)$ by $\mathbb{E}(Y \, \mid \, X = x) = g(x)$.  Indeed, after changing measure, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\forall A \in F \quad \mathbb{E}(Y : X^{-1}(A)) &= \int_{X^{-1}(A)} \mathbb{E}(Y \, \mid \, \sigma(X))(\omega) \, \mathbb{P}(d\omega) \\
&= \int_{X^{-1}(A)} g(X(\omega)) \, \mathbb{P}(d \omega) \\
&= \int_{A} g(x) \, \mu_{X}(dx) \\
&= \int_{A} \mathbb{E}(Y \, \mid \, X = x) \, \mu_{X}(dx).
\end{align*}

Comment: Why should $g$ be a function from $\Bbb R$? Or to $\Bbb R$ as you stated later? Actually it should be a function $g: E \to E$

Comment: Changed $\tilde{Y}$ for a less misleading notation. In the second part of your post, you might want to treat the more general (and more "suggestive") case of $E(Y\mathbf 1_A)$ for every $A$ in $\sigma(X)$, rather than simply proving that $E(Y)=E(E(Y\mid X))$, which does not say that much about $E(Y\mid X)$.

Comment: I took your suggestion.

Comment: @Gono, I confused which of $X$ or $Y$ was $E$-valued.  I corrected the post to reflect the OP's choice $X : \Omega \to E$ and $Y : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: When you say $Y$ is $\sigma(X)$ measurable, I assume that you mean in addition that it is NOT $\Sigma$ measurable?

Comment: No they do not (why should they?).

Comment: @Programmer2134, $\sigma(X)$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\Sigma$, as you point out in your original post.  Therefore, $\sigma(X)$-measurable functions are necessarily $\Sigma$-measurable.  Not also that if $g : E \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, then $g \circ X$ will be $\Sigma$-measurable (by composition) so there's no inconsistency.

Comment: @Did, I edited the question, to explain my confusion on this point.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Your definition of $\sigma(X)$ is wrong… actually it is: $$\sigma(X)=\{s\in \Sigma: s=X^{-1}(t)\text{ for } t\in F\}$$So measurability of functions is always connected to the mesaruability of pre-images. There are no restrictions to the image of a measurable set. The image of a measurable set is not necessarily measurable… but the pre-image of a measurable set has to be measurable.

2.) Your question doesn't make sense at all. You consider $E(X|Y)$ but with this notation you already fixed a measure! Usually if you write "$E[X]$" and state "Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space" you mean "$E(X|Y)$ w.r.t the measure $P$".

Check the definition of the expectation… it depends on the measure. So if you want to make it kind of "arbitrary" for a random measure $\mu$ you should write $E_\mu$ instead.

And then, ofc $E_\mu(X|Y)$ is a conditional expectations depending on the choice of $\mu$

Comment: In regards to (2), the OP says "Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space" at the outset.

Comment: Yeah… ofc he fixes the measure in the beginning… but later he stated "up to a measure"… added a sentence to point that out.

Comment: @Gono, What I meant with "only uniquely defined up to a measure on $\sigma(X)$", is: There are many different random variables that are consistent with the conditions of $E(Y|X)$, so that the definition does not pinpoint a unique random variable. However, so long as two probability measures agree on the probabilities of the elements of $\sigma(X)$ (that is, they don't have to agree on the elements of $\Sigma$), then they will all produce the same pushforwarded measure of $E(Y|X)$ on $R$. This is why I think it makes sense to consider $E(Y|X)$ to be a random variable on $E$ rather than $\Omega$