# Intuition for Conditional Expectation definition

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

I am trying to understand the definition of conditional expectation with respect to a sub-$\sigma$-algebra. I think the top answer for this question: [Why this weird definition of conditional expectation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2572101/why-this-weird-definition-of-conditional-expectation) is similar to what I'm after but it didn't quite make sense to me. The example given in my lecture notes is as follows.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space. $X$ is a random variable and $A\in \mathcal A$. Suppose $\mathcal F = \sigma$ ({A}) = {$\emptyset,A,A^{c},\Omega$}, a certain sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal A$. We define the conditional expectation given $\mathcal F$ as the random variable on $\Omega$ given by

$\mathbb E[X|\mathcal F]:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$, where $\mathbb E[X|\mathcal F](\omega)=$

\begin{cases} 
      \mathbb E[X|A] & \forall\omega\in A \\
      \mathbb E[X|A^{c}] & \forall\omega\in A^{c} \
        \ 
   \end{cases}

I would like to know what this function is telling us. Why is it useful to have a function that, when given an outcome, tells us the expectation of the random variable given a larger set? If we have the outcome, isn't the expected value of the random variable just $X(\omega)$? Would it not make more sense for this function to have the domain $\mathcal A$?

**EDIT:**
Is the idea that we don't know the exact $\omega\in\Omega$, only that $\omega\in A$ or $\omega\in A^{c}$? Since if we knew the exact $\omega$ we would know $X(\omega)$, therefore not need to estimate $X$?

Comment: There are lots of cases where we find $\mathbb EX$ by applying the rule: $$\mathbb EX=\mathbb E[X\mid A]P(A)+\mathbb E[X\mid A^{\complement}]P(A^{\complement})$$This can be seen as a taster of the usefulness of conditional expectations.

Comment: I can see how that follows from the definition of conditional expectation of a random variable with respect to an event, however I still don't understand the motivation for the definition with respect to a sub-$\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Do you agree that the function $X\mapsto\mathbb EX$ is a very useful function? Well, actually it can be recognized as the function $\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal F]$ where $\mathcal F$ denotes the trivial $\sigma$-algebra $\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$. I can imagine though that also this might not be convincing, and that you are still wondering about this weird definition. Do not despair. If you become more familiar with the concept then - I believe so - it will reveal its usefulness more and more.

Comment: It might be that intuition/usefulness was a bad description of what I was after. What I want to understand is why evaluating this random variable $E[X|\mathcal F](\omega)$ at a known value of $\omega\in\Omega$ is not just the same as $X(\omega)$. Why do we have to look at the set $A$ when we already know the outcome that occurred i.e the value of $X$ that occurred?

Comment: Let $\mathcal F$ be the $\sigma$-algebra as defined in your question and let $X$ be a random variable that can take at least $3$ distinct values. Then $\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal F]$ is by definition $\mathcal F$-measurable. Consequently this random variable can take at most $2$ values. This in  in contrast with the original random variable $X$ which can take at least $3$ values. So some $\omega\in\Omega$ must exist with $X(\omega)\neq\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal F](\omega)$.