# $\sigma$-Algebras generated by random variables and measurability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am working on some exercises about probability theory and there's an exercise that says:

Let $X_1,X_2..X_n$ be real r.v. say if the following statements are True or False., and then gives some functions of $X_i$ and asks if they are measurable wrt to the $\sigma$-Algebra generated by some r.v.
One example would be:

$X_1^2 + 2cos(X_2) - sin(X_3)$ is measurable wrt $\sigma(X_1,X_2^2,X_3)$

I do not want to focus particularly on this example (yet insights about it are welcomed), I have general doubts.

To clarify I am working with the following definition: The $\sigma$-Algebra generated by a r.v. X is defined as: $\{ X^{-1}(B); B \in \mathcal{B}\}$ which is the smallest $\sigma$-Algebra $\mathcal{F}$ where $X$ is measurable.

Which I understand as something like "the set of events $\omega$ in $\Omega$ that generates the sets $B$ that is the set of the possible values of the r.v."

With that in mind,

1. How is the $\sigma$-Algebra generated by $X$ any different from just "all the events such that $X(\omega)$ exists?
2. When they clarify "..such that $X$ is measurable." that is because for $X$ to be measurable it needs a $\sigma$-Algebra and therefore any set smaller than that would lose the $\sigma$-Algebra attribute and therefore not be measurable?
3. How $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(X^2)$ differ?
4. Is $sin(X)$ measurable wrt $\sigma(X)$? Is $\sigma(sin(X))$ in $\sigma(X)$?
5. Isn't the $\sigma(X)$ for $X$ real r.v., just the set of Borel sets in where the r.v. is defined? (e.g. if $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then it would be $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ )
6. When something is measurable wrt to a $\sigma$-Algebra and when it is not?

As I was writing the post I realized it was quite difficult even to think about the questions, so please if you need me to express myself in a different way, please let me know.

Any comment that might help me get a **better understanding of $\sigma$-Algebras generated by r.v.** is extremely useful for me, so thanks in advance.

Comment: It might help to think about $\sigma(f(X))$ as what you know if you knew the realisation of $f(X)$.

Comment: Do you mean it in the context of a concrete random experiment or the general case? @TheoreticalEconomist

Comment: $\sigma(X)$ knows whether $X$ is positive or not, but $\sigma(X^2)$ does not. Both know about $|X|$. (Where "knows" has some meaning I would explain with hand gestures, but cannot precisely state in this little postcard.)

Comment: @nico_so Not sure what exactly you mean by that question, sorry. It might help you to read the first part of my answer here to clarify what I mean when I talk about thinking about $\sigma$-algebras as "knowing" things: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2581172/388944

Comment: What I meant is that "the realisation of $f(X)$" mean like something concrete happened, but we could think that actually it did not yet happened and have like a mathematical expression ready for when it happens, and wheter some $B_i$ happens, THEN we know something new. @TheoreticalEconomist

Comment: @kimchilover So $\sigma(X)$ is "more useful" than $\sigma(X^2)$ in the sense that it has more information about $X$.

Comment: Yes.  The technical term is "finer": $\sigma(X)$ makes finer distinctions than $\sigma(X^2)$.

Comment: Thank you, could you please elaborate on how this affects the measurability or not of different functions of $X_1$ ($X_1$,  $X_2^2$,  $sin(X_1)$, or any other example) with respect to those $\sigma$-Algebras? Because that is one of the points where I get lost @kimchilover